# get record by id in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join, return

I have a problem passing values ​​in a column according to the id of the product

The join tables is running but returns all column values. 
I think the solution is simple but I am not able to get there. 
Please some help to solve this issue?

Here is the tables

## TABLE: tbl_lining

id,
article,
description,
observations

## TABLE:products

[image: [Table Products - picture](http://www.webmark.com.pt/pics/products.png)]

Function used in model

## MODEL

```
 public function getliningsale($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('products.id', $id);  // Also mention table name here
    $query = $this->db->get();    
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $data->result();
}
```

## CONTROLLER

```
function liningsale()
{   

$data['lining'] = $this->sales_model->getliningsale($id);
$this->load->view('add', $data);
}
```

Trying to display one record according product id

## VIEW

```
echo '<td><input class="span1 tran2" name="lining\'+ count +\'" type="text"';
echo 'value="';
 foreach ($liningsale as $valor) {
 echo $valor->article;
 echo '-';
 echo $valor->description; 
 echo '">';
 }

echo '</td>';
```

Instead of that, is displaying all records

[image: [Table Result - picture](http://www.webmark.com.pt/pics/result.png)]

Comment: You have forgot add the where clause in ur query

Comment: Hi Amit

I've tried with the clause but without success. The page don't load.

Can you give me some help here?

Comment: $this->db->where('id', $id);

Comment: you have to use the product id you want in your query.. but your model doesnt show any product id variable.. post your controller code.

Comment: Like this?

`public function getleathersale()
   {
   
$this->db->select('*')
   
  
->from('tbl_leather')
   
->join('products', 'tbl_leather.id=products.leather', 'left');
 
$this->db->where('id', $id);  
$data = $this->db->get ();
return $data->result ();

   } 
`
The page view don't load

Comment: Where are you defining the $id?? you have to get it from somewhere right.. controller may be, add your controller code to your question

Comment: Sorry SS56 

You are right. I forgot the controller.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/../sma/modules/sales/models/sales_model.php on line 1109`The problem is that I have never worked with codeigniter. 
This is a working script, where I have made some changes, which are working for now. 
 
Would be too much if I asked you to help me in this issue?

Comment: no.. I would be happy to help..

Comment: Added the function to the controller. What is missing?

'add' is add.php page that will display querys

Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/....sales/models/sales_model.php on line 1108

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving any value **`($id)`** here,

```
public function getliningsale()   {
```

Modify you **Model** code as below:

```
public function getliningsale($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('products.id', $id);  // Also mention table name here
    $query = $this->db->get();    
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $data->result();
}
```

Comment: Hi Parag 
Now page loads and returns values except of the table tbl_lining. 

It may be something related to the controller, above? 
Thanks –

Comment: make it `inner join` instead of `left`

Comment: `public function getliningsale($id)
   {
   $this->db->select('*')
   ->from('products')
   
   ->join('tbl_lining', 'products.lining=tbl_lining.id', 'INNER')
   ->where('products.id', $id);
 $data = $this->db->get ();
    return $data->result ();

   } `

This way records of tbl_lining don't return

Answer (score 0):

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return **$data-**>result();
```

I think you must use 
`$query->result()` 
and not 
`$data->result`